# R Shiny - use google authenticator to allow people with a certain type of email address to log in

Tags: r, shiny, google-authenticator

I'm trying to build an app that allows users in my organisation to submit requests for some Analysis. It's a very basic Shiny App where people input parameters and then this data is inserted in a table in redshift.

I've added a Google Authenticator using

> `shinyApp(gar_shiny_ui(ui, login_ui = silent_auth), server)`

at the end of my app.R

and this at the top of my server function

> `gar_shiny_auth(session)`

(I'm using googleAuthR package)

This adds a Google Authentication UI before my App's UI but the problem is

**It allows any google email to access my app**

and I want to add a filter which only allows **email addresses that end with myorganisation.com** to access the app.

Does anyone know how to achieve that? I would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I found a solution that sort of works.

In addition to what I've written in the question,

1. we need to define the UI in the server
2. Get user info and extract email from his/her google login
3. Use this email to determine if the person is from your organisation
4. If the person is from your organisation, show the main UI else show a UI which says 'You cannot access this tool'

   ```
       #Function to get google user data which will be used for checking if the user comes from your organisation
   user_info <- function(){
     f <- gar_api_generator("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo",
                            "GET",
                            data_parse_function = function(x) x
     )
     f()
   }

   #UI code based on Output coming via server code
       ui<-uiOutput('myUI')


   #Server side code to do all the lifting
      server = function(input, output,session) {
           gar_shiny_auth(session)

           #Check if user has already logged in with google authentication
           gmail='john.doe@unkwown.com'  
           tryCatch({
             x<- user_info()
             gmail=x$email
             print(gmail)}) 
           print(gmail)

           #Create a different UI based on where the user comes from (MyOrg or Not)
           output$myUI <- renderUI({

             if(grepl('@myorganisation.com',gmail)){
               ui = fluidPage(
                 shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                 title='Your Product',
                 theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                 img(src = "mycompany_logo.png", height = 200, width = 400),

                 sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(write whatever you want)
                   ,
                   mainPanel( write whatever you want)
                 )
               )} 
             else {
               ui = fluidPage(mainPanel(
                 h4("My Company Data Team Presents", allign="center"),
                 h1("My Tool", allign="center"),
                 p("Tool that makes analysing any and everything ",
                   em("incredibly easy "),
                   "with a simple click."),
                 br(),
                 p("- But unfortunately, your account does not have the rights to ",
                   em("access "),
                   "this tool.")))  }
           })
       shinyApp(gar_shiny_ui(ui, login_ui = silent_auth), server)
   ```

Comment: Check [`shinyauthr`](https://github.com/PaulC91/shinyauthr) for some inspiration on how to serve different UIs depending on user authenthication.

Comment: @AndreaDodet Thanks, but the goal is to use the google authenticator as my team members can change and thus having google authenticate their email address is the best way to securely allow access

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I've pointed at that resource in case you want to build a package for it. I believe that `req(credentials()$user_auth` and an `observe` it's way cleaner than wrapping ui inside an if/else statement (kinda similar as you'd do with Python wrappers).

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it :)